# Directives inside an ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I'm seeing some odd behaviour when I put custom directives inside a div with an ng-show.

If I define the html as:

```
<div ng-show="service.searchResults">
    <fig-search-type-filters />

    <fig-filter-search />       

    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="vm.grid"></div>
</div>
```

then when the show condition is true it shows just `fig-search-type-filters` content. All the rest is elided from the html.
However, if I wrap each directive as follows:

```
<div ng-show="service.searchResults">
    <fig-search-type-filters />
</div>

<div ng-show="service.searchResults">
    <fig-filter-search />       
</div>

<div ng-show="service.searchResults">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="vm.grid"></div>
</div>
```

then `fig-search-type-filters`, `fig-filter-search` and the grid are displayed as I expect. Why is this?

If I move the ng-show condition inside the template for each directives then again only the `fig-search-type-filters` appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do this:

```
<div ng-show="service.searchResults">
    <fig-search-type-filters> </fig-search-type-filters>

    <fig-filter-search> </fig-filter-search>        

    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="vm.grid"></div>
</div
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the problem coming from a WPF background where self-closing tags are allowed.